# Split student list that has format like: 0001 William Bill Junior 8.5

Tags: c++, char

I need to split a list of student like this into ID, Name and score. This is an exercise so no string is allowed, only `char`

```
0001 William Bob 8.5
0034 Howard Stark 9.5
0069 Natalia Long Young 8
```

Here's the code

```
int readFile(list& a) {
    char str[MAX];
    short i = 0;
    ifstream fi(IN);
    if (!fi)
        return 0;
    while (!fi.eof()) {
        fi.getline(str, MAX - 1);
        char* temp = strtok(str, " ");
        if (temp == NULL)
            continue;
        strcpy(a.sv[i].id, temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "0123456789");
        strcpy(a.sv[i].name, temp);
        temp = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        a.sv[i].grade = atof(temp);
        i++;
    }
    a.size = i;
    fi.close();
    return 1;
}
```

Using `strtok()` I have splitted ID and Name successfully, but the score are

```
0.5
0.5
0
```

I know the problem is because of  `temp = strtok(NULL, "0123456789");` but I don't know how to fix it, are there any delimiters beside `"0123456789"`, or can I move the pointer back?

---

This is my attempt to fix the `while(!file.eof())` and solve my problem.
Here's my heading and structs:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#define IN "D:\\Input.txt"
#define OUT "D:\\Output.txt"
#define MAX 40
using namespace std;
struct sv{
    char id[MAX], name[MAX] , sex[MAX];
    float grade;
};
struct dssv {
    sv sv[MAX];
    short size;
};
```

And here's my function:

```
int readFile(dssv& a) {
    char str[MAX];
    short i = 0;
    ifstream fi(IN);
    if (!fi)
        return 0;
    while (fi>>a.sv[i].id && fi.getline(str, MAX)) {
        char* name = strchr(str, ' ');
        int pos = strrchr(name, ' ') - name;
        char* score = str + pos;
        strcpy(name + pos, "\0"); \\null-terminate to remove the score.
        strcpy(a.sv[i].name, name + 1);
        a.sv[i].grade = atof(score + 1);
        i++;
    }
    a.size = i;
    fi.close();
    return 1;
}
```

Still figuring out how to fix the eof() and why do I need two pointers `char* name` and `char* score` instead of one and reuse it.

Comment: You definitely cannot move the pointer back. If you have to use `strtok`, I would split the string using `" "` as the delimiter. Use `strcat` to patch the name back together.

Comment: OTOH, if you aren't required to use `strtok`, then I would recommend `strcspn` to search for the first digit.  `strcspn` doesn't modify the string like `strtok` does. So you can find the first digit, then back up, and insert the `'\0'` character yourself.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: In particular, you can't use `while (!fi.eof())` to predict that a future read won't fail. Status-reporting functions report on the past, they do not predict the future.

Comment: `int pos = strrchr(name, ' ') - name;` in your update doesn't really provide a position, but instead provides the number of characters between the first and last space in the line. To bracket name you want to advance `name` to the first character in `name`, e.g. `while (name && isspace(*name)) name++;` You want to save the pointer from `strrchr` and after you compute `score` backup to the last char name nul-terminating spaces as you go, `char *end = strrchr(name, ' ');` and `while (end > name && --end && isspace(*end)) *end = 0;` Now just `strcpy(a.sv[i].name, name);`, no + 1, etc..

Comment: Also, the reason you want to open your file in the parent function and pass an open `std::ifstream` reference as a parameter -- is -- if the file cannot be successfully opened for reading in the caller, there is no need to make the function call to begin with `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You have started off on the wrong foot. See [Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong). While there are a number of ways to separate the information into `id, name, score`, probably the most basic is to simply read an entire line of data into a temporary buffer (character array), and then to use `sscanf` to separate `id, name & score`.

The parsing with `sscanf` is not difficult, the only caveat being that your `name` can contain whitespace, so you cannot simply use `"%s"` as the *format specifier* to extract the name. This is mitigated by your `score` field always starting with a *digit* and *digits* do not occur in names (there are always exceptions to the rule -- and it can be handled with a simple parse with a pair of pointers, but for the basic example we will make this formatting assumption)

To make data handling simpler and be able to coordinate all the information for one student as a single object (allowing you to create an array of them to hold all student information) you can use a simple `stuct`. Declaring a few constants to set the sizes for everything avoids using *Magic-Numbers* throughout your code. (though for the `sscanf` *field-width* modifiers, actual numbers must be used as you cannot use constants or variables for the width modifier) For example, your struct could be:

```
#define MAXID    8      /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXNM   64
#define MAXSTD 128
#define MAXLN MAXSTD

typedef struct {        /* simple struct to hold student data */
    char id[MAXID];
    char name[MAXNM];
    double score;
} student_t;
```

(and POSIX reserves the `"_t"` suffix for extension of types, but there won't be a `"student_t"` type -- but in general be aware of the restriction though you will see the `"_t"` suffix frequently)

The basic approach is to read a line from your file into a buffer (with either `fgets` or POSIX `getline`) and then pass the line to `sscanf`. You condition your read loop on the successful read of each line so your read stops when `EOF` is reached. For separating the values with `sscanf`, it is convenient to use a temporary struct to hold the separated values. That way if the separation is successful, you simply add the temporary struct to your array. To read the students into an array of `student_t` you could do:

```
size_t readstudents (FILE *fp, student_t *s)
{
    char buf[MAXLN];    /* temporary array (buffer) to hold line */
    size_t n = 0;       /* number of students read from file */

    /* read each line in file until file read or array full */
    while (n < MAXSTD && fgets (buf, MAXLN, fp)) {
        student_t tmp = { .id = "" };   /* temporary stuct to fill */
        /* extract id, name and score from line, validate */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%7s %63[^0-9] %lf", tmp.id, tmp.name, &tmp.score) == 3) {
            char *p = strrchr (tmp.name, 0);    /* pointer to end of name */
            /* backup overwriting trailing spaces with nul-terminating char */
            while (p && --p >= tmp.name && *p == ' ')
                *p = 0;
            s[n++] = tmp;   /* add temp struct to array, increment count */
        }
    }

    return n;   /* return number of students read from file */
}
```

Now let's take a minute and look at the `sscanf` *format string* used:

```
    sscanf (buf, "%7s %63[^0-9] %lf", tmp.id, tmp.name, &tmp.score)
```

Above, with the line in `buf`, the format string used is `"%7s %63[^0-9] %lf"`. Each character array type uses a *field-width* modifier to limit the number of characters stored in the associated array to *one-less-than* the number of characters available. This protects the array bounds and ensures that each string stored is *nul-terminated*. The `"%7s"` is self-explanatory - read at most 7-characters into what will be the `id`.

The next conversion specifier for the name is `"%63[^0-9]"` which is a bit more involved as it uses the `"%[...]` character class conversion specifier with the match inverted by use of `'^'` as the first character. The characters in the class being digits `0-9`, the conversion specifier reads up to 63 character that do Not include digits. This will have the side-effect of including the spaces between `name` and `score` in `name`. Thankfully they are simple enough to remove by getting a pointer to the end of the string with `strrchr (tmp.name, 0);` and then backing up checking if the character is a `' '` (space) and overwriting it with a *nul-terminating* character (e.g. `'\0'` or numeric equivalent `0`).

The last part of the `sscanf` conversion, `"%lf"` is simply the conversion specifier for the `double` value for `score`.

Note: most importantly, the conversion is validated by ***checking the return*** of the call to `sscanf` is `3` -- the number of conversions requested. If all conversions succeed into the temporary struct `tmp`, then `tmp` is simply added to your array of struct.

To call the function from `main()` and read the student information, you simply declare an array of `student_t` to hold the information, open and validate your data file is open for reading, and make a call to `readstudents` capturing the return to validate that student information was actually read from the file. Then you can make use of the data as you wish (it is simply output below):

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    student_t students[MAXSTD] = {{ .id = "" }};    /* array of students */
    size_t nstudents = 0;                           /* count of students */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    /* read students from file, validate return, if zero, handle error */
    if ((nstudents = readstudents (fp, students)) == 0) {
        fputs ("error: no students read from file.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nstudents; i++)  /* output each student data */
        printf ("%-8s  %-24s  %g\n", 
                students[i].id, students[i].name, students[i].score);

    return 0;
}
```

All that remains is including the required headers, `stdio.h` and `string.h` and testing:

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_stud_id_name_score dat/stud_id_name_no.txt
0001      William Bob               8.5
0034      Howard Stark              9.5
0069      Natalia Long Young        8
```

It works as needed.

Note, this is the most basic way of separating the values and only works based on the assumption that your `score` field starts with a digit.

You can eliminate that assumption by manually parsing the information you need by reading each line in the same manner, but instead of using `sscanf`, simply declare a pair of pointers to isolate `id, name & score` manually. The basic approach being to advance a pointer to the first whitespace and read `id`, skip the following whitespace and position the pointer at the beginning of `name`. Start from the end of the line with the other and backup to the first whitespace at the end and read `score`, then continue backing up positioning the pointer in the first space after `name`. Then just copy the characters between your start and end pointer to `name` and *nul-terminate*. It is more involved from a pointer-arithmetic standpoint, but just as simple. (that is left to you)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. Normally, you would dynamically declare your array of students and allocate/reallocate as needed to handle any number of students from the file. (or from an actual C++ standpoint use the `vector` and `string` types that the standard template library provides and let the containers handle the memory allocation for you) That too is just one additional layer that you can add to add flexibility to your code.

---

**C++ Implementation**

I apologize for glossing over a C++ solution, but given your use of C string functions in your posted code, I provided a C solution in return. A C++ solution making using the `std::string` and `std::vector` is not that much different other than from a storage standpoint. The parsing of the three values is slightly different, where the entire line is read into `id` and `name` and then the `score` is obtained from the portion of the line held in `name` and then those characters erased from `name`.

Changing the C `FILE*` to `std::ifstream` and the array of `student_t` to a `std::vector<student_t>`, your `readstudents()` function could be written as:

```
void readstudents (std::ifstream& fp, std::vector<student_t>& s)
{
    std::string buf;    /* temporary array (buffer) to hold line */
    student_t tmp;      /* temporary stuct to fill */

    /* read each line in file until file read or array full */
    while (fp >> tmp.id && getline(fp, tmp.name)) {
        /* get offset to beginning digit within tmp.name */
        size_t  offset = tmp.name.find_first_of("0123456789"),
                nchr;   /* no. of chars converted with stod */
        if (offset == std::string::npos)    /* validate digit found */
            continue;
        /* convert to double, save in tmp.score */
        tmp.score = std::stod(tmp.name.substr(offset), &nchr);
        if (!nchr)      /* validate digits converted */
            continue;
        /* backup using offset to erase spaces after name */
        while (tmp.name.at(--offset) == ' ')
            tmp.name.erase(offset);

        s.push_back(tmp);   /* add temporary struct to vector */
    }
}
```

(**note:** the return type is changed to `void` as the `.size()` of the student vector can be validated on return).

The complete example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct student_t {      /* simple struct to hold student data */
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    double score;
};

void readstudents (std::ifstream& fp, std::vector<student_t>& s)
{
    std::string buf;    /* temporary array (buffer) to hold line */
    student_t tmp;      /* temporary stuct to fill */

    /* read each line in file until file read or array full */
    while (fp >> tmp.id && getline(fp, tmp.name)) {
        /* get offset to beginning digit within tmp.name */
        size_t  offset = tmp.name.find_first_of("0123456789"),
                nchr;   /* no. of chars converted with stod */
        if (offset == std::string::npos)    /* validate digit found */
            continue;
        /* convert to double, save in tmp.score */
        tmp.score = std::stod(tmp.name.substr(offset), &nchr);
        if (!nchr)      /* validate digits converted */
            continue;
        /* backup using offset to erase spaces after name */
        while (tmp.name.at(--offset) == ' ')
            tmp.name.erase(offset);

        s.push_back(tmp);   /* add temporary struct to vector */
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::vector<student_t> students {};     /* array of students */

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate one argument given for filename */
        std::cerr << "error: filename required as 1st argument.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream fp (argv[1]);  /* use filename provided as 1st argument */

    if (!fp.good()) {   /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "file open failed";
        return 1;
    }
    /* read students from file, validate return, if zero, handle error */
    readstudents (fp, students);
    if (students.size() == 0) {
        std::cerr << "error: no students read from file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto s : students)  /* output each student data */
        std::cout << std::left << std::setw(8) << s.id
                << std::left << std::setw(24) << s.name
                << s.score << '\n';
}
```

(the output is the same -- aside from 2-spaces omitted between the values)

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Also, my apologies for the slow reply. There are so many new things that I don't even know where to ask. Below is my attempt to fix the `while(!file.eof())` (still not quite know how to fix it), and try to "copy the characters between your start and end pointer to name and nul-terminate". Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: The `while(!feof.eof())` problem is that after your read of the last line of data, `.eof()` will NOT be set even though the *file-position-indicator* is positioned just prior to `EOF`, and you check `while(!feof.eof())` and enter another iteration. Your call to `fi.getline(str, MAX - 1);` fails and there is no valid string in `str`, but since you don't check the return of `getline`, you `char* temp = strtok(str, " ");` invoking *Undefined Behavior* calling `strtok` on `str` which is *indeterminate* at that point. I'll find a pointer parse example for you.

Comment: Here is a decent example of using a start-pointer and end-pointer to locate the longest word in a string: [Finding Longest Word in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212190/finding-longest-word-in-a-string/57212725?r=SearchResults&s=2|52.6046#57212725). The process of manually working down a string is the same regardless of whether it is C/C++. The only difference is C++ STL provides the `.substr()` member function that can replace the manual `memcpy` and *nul-termination*.

Comment: Here is an example of your function using a pair of pointers to parse the information: [Read Student ID Name Score](https://susepaste.org/77547902)